# Weak convergence of fourier series of $L^1$ function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, weak-convergence

If $D_N(f)$ is the partial sums of the Fourier series of an $L^1(S^1)$ function $f$, my professor claimed that we have weak convergence of $D_N(f)$ to $f$ in the sense of $\displaystyle \int D_N(f)\cdot g\rightarrow \int f\cdot g$ for any $g\in C^\infty(S^1)$. (Note, I think it's false if $g\in L^1(S^1)$ in general) Why is this claim true?

Comment: The choice of notation is unfortunate, more typically $S_n$ or $s_n$ used. In the context of Fourier series, $D_N$ is often used for the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: I agree, sorry about the confusing notation there.

Comment: No problem, just mildly confusing initially :-). This may be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/110993/31729

Comment: @copper.hat that's a little surprising, but I guess lots of things in this area are.

Comment: I guess if the above was true you could pick $g=\operatorname{sgn} (D_N(f)-f)$ (or the complex equivalent) and get $\|D_n(f)-f\|_1 \to 0$.

Comment: Yes, the plethora of results is confusing.

Comment: In the question your linked, the OP says "whereas if $f$ ranges over Schwartz distributions and $h$ over $C^\infty$ functions then the answer is positive (because $f\cdot h$ will be smooth). " which seems relevant. But I'm not sure I understand their argument. It will be nice if someone can elaborate on that to enlighten me a bit. :)

Comment: @Macrophage I do not follow the OP's remarks in that regard.

Comment: For smooth functions, pull the $S_n$ operator from f to g and use that you have uniform convergence $S_n(g)\to g$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment, but what does it mean to pull the operator from f to g? It will be very nice if you can expand that into an answer to this question. Thanks again! @PhoemueX